# Is it possible to send a Primitive Array through ksoap2?

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2

Now matter how I format my request property, it get a:

```
Cannot Serialize: [int, int, int]
```

error. I have no clue what else to try. I've tried:

```
ArrayList<Integer>, int[], Vector<Integer>, List<Integer>
```

None of these worked. The one that I got the closest on was Vector.. It seemed to have serialized the Vector Objects fine, but when I sent it to the Web Service method I got the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeError Mismatched types
```

Yes, I have changed the input parameter for the method to Vector and made sure that I've imported the same types of Vectors.

This is my Web Service and my app, so, I do have full range of it. I am willing to change any portion of both the app and the WS. If you have any ideas please let me know. This is how I am creating my request for the Web Service:

This is a full method that I am trying to use the Vector in.

```
            public ArrayList<Contacts> getLocationslist(Vector<Integer> list){

            ArrayList<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
            String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:getLocationsList";
            String METHOD_NAME = "getLocationsList";

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
            request.addProperty("arg0", list);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
                new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                   
                int i = 0;
                SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                while (i < resultsRequestSOAP.getPropertyCount()){

                Contacts cont = new Contacts();

                 try {
                        Ksoap2ResultParser.parseBusinessObject(resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(i).toString(), cont);

                     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                contacts.add(cont);
                i = i + 1;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return contacts;
        }
```

I am counting on you SO!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more attempts, I just went with using a String Tokenizer.

```
            ArrayList<Integer> clist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(list);

        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            String id = st.nextToken(",");
            clist.add(Integer.parseInt(id));
        }
```

Just Create a String that contains all of the Values that you wish to send in an Array. I created the Array, then used

```
 for(Int i : intsList){
String list = list + i + ",";
}
```

Then let the tokenizer split the values by each ",".

Which worked well. I'm just going to assume at this point that Ksoap2 cannot Serialize any array type. Thanks Guys!
-Ninn